# Check if the file is created by a process or by user using C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, filesystems

I am watching my system root drive (C:\) for all files and folders change notifications. I am using ReadDirectoryChangesW() WIN API to achieve this using VC++, Now, I am able to monitor all kind of change notifications for files i.e. Rename, Delete, Creation...

However, my problem is that I only want to monitor the files and folders changes, which are done by the user manually instead of a process or a program.

Because, if I watch root folder with ReadDirectoryChangesW() WIN API, I get thousands of change notifications in just couple of minutes, as most of temp and data files are created either by OS or by third party installed applications...

How can I only monitor files changes done by user manually (i.e. changes only initiated by user with the help of mouse or keyboard).

Comment: Why monitor the root directory?  Can't it monitor some application-specific directory instead?

Comment: But the user has to *use a program* to create a file.  It's not like people are going down to their disks with tiny magnets....

Comment: To check if it has been started programmatically check up the process tree. This can be queried with `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`.

Comment: [User Friendly](http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=20091201) — editing inodes by hand, with magnets!

Comment: "Manually"? What does "manually" mean??? Everything in Windows is done by processes.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Tim: I want to monitor all files and folders changes in root folder limited to user only, however using ReadDirectoryChangesW() gives me all the change notifications done by either user or some other process programmatically..
I only want the notifications for files changes done by user directly ( creating or deleting a file) or through a program like( downloading a file from browser or saving a document from word)

Suppose I have a chat messenger installed, which continuously creates and deletes some specific files in its temp folder..so I do not want these notifications..

Comment: Dubious as normal users don't have write access to the root of the system drive. It will need to be proxied via other programs.

Comment: Don't forget [butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: You restated your question without explaining the problem you are trying to solve. Try to describe the problem without going into the solution you posted in your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to differentiate between user-initiated activities and application-initiated activities.  If you think about it, user-initiated activities are done with programs, whether that be Windows Explorer itself, a DOS prompt, Notepad, whatever.  From the OS's perspective, everything ultimately goes through the same file system API, which is where the monitoring occurs.

Comment: I think user initiated activities would be either achieved by Windows Explorer or DOS prompt, so in this case we can filter all the notification changes with their Process , which initiated that change..this way we can filter out the third party software change notification, which they are carrying out in their data folder for their own usage...
 Pls correct me if I am wrong !
Thanks

Comment: @WindowsProgrammer, but what about other applications that create files, like for instance downloading a file from a browser or using a spreadsheet application to save a file?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is eventually in the location of files. User documents properly belong in My Documents; files that belong to an application belong in CommonAppData, temporary files for a single user go in his AppData.

Of course, if a user "manually" uses Notepad to open a log file in AppData then there's no way to discover this.